# jQuery .css() does not work with background-url

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

I'm trying to add a dynamic background using the .css() property of jQuery. The background URL is provided through AJAX:

```
            function requestbg(cusa) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'api/bg.php',
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: {id: cusa},
                    success: function(response) {
                        if(response != "") {
                            var url = response;
                            $("body").css("background-url", url);
                            console.log(response);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

When changing `background-url` to `background-color`, it does work. Weird, because in the console I log the response, and it does return a URL. Figured there might be a space somewhere, checked it multiple times but nothing.

Does anybody know why this would not work?

Comment: In CSS there is no such property "background-url". Explain what you mean by "background-url".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("body").css({ "background-image": 'url('+url+')'});
```

Comment: That indeed seems to work perfectly. Just for future reference, is there any particular reason why my code wouldn't work and this does?

Comment: Sorry about that , currently on my phone answering via app. In short, 'background-url' is not a case property. 'background-image' is what you should be using, supplying a value matching the required format 'url(your_image_url)'. Hope this clarifies my answer a bit

Answer (score 1):

`background-url` is an invalid css property. You're looking for [background-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image):

> The background-image CSS property sets one or more background images
>   on an element.

Adjust your code as so and the follow should work.

```
$("body").css({ "background-image": 'url(' +url +')' });
```

Comment: I've got it working. Thanks for the help and explanation, it's appreciated :)